# Drag and drop reactJs using beautiful dnd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to practice #Drag and Drop [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-drag-and-drop-in-react-with-react-beautiful-dnd/)
So I created a state which includes a number of boxes and inside these boxes, there should be an icon that I suppose to be able to move to any of the generated boxes
so the problem with my code is that when picking the icon it ***renders all the boxes*** instead of one box

```
const [pointPlace, setPointPlace] = useState([...Array(162).keys()]);
 
const handleOnDragEnd = result => {
    const items = Array.from(pointPlace);
    const [reorderboxes] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderboxes);
    setPointPlace(items);
};



return (
    <Box>
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId="pointsContainer">
                {provided => (
                    <Box
                        className={classes.container}
                        display={'flex'}
                        flexGrow={1}
                        flexWrap={'wrap'}
                        alignItems={'center'}
                        justifyContent={'center'}
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.droppableProps}
                    >
                        {pointPlace.map((index, id) => (
                            <Draggable draggableId="draggable-point" index={index} key={id}>
                                {provided => (
                                    <Box className={classes.box} ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                                        {point} <p className={classes.boxNumber}>{index}</p>
                                    </Box>
                                )}
                            </Draggable>
                        ))}
                    </Box>
                )}
            </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
    </Box>
);
```